# Python3 replace ord() and chr()

Tags: python-3.x, chr, ord

```
        for i in word:
            c = ord(i) - int(key)
            if c < 97:
                c = c + 26
            b = chr(c)
            text += b
```

Is there another way to replace this without ord() and chr()?

Thank you very much!

Comment: ord() and chr() are built into python. Any specific reason to replace them?

Comment: You can precompute a mapping (using dict) from source characters to destination characters, and use this dict to substitute one by one char from word.

Comment: If there is some special reason to omit chr/ord, e.g. some school task, then also you can convert string to bytes using `bs = word.encode('utf-16')` then change some bytes and convert back to string using `word = bs.decode('utf-16')`.

Comment: And make `key` an int  before the loop

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code using [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/) module plus [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32) encoding/decoding. This code will be very fast for large data, and needs no Python loops.

`numpy` module is easily installed using `python -m pip install numpy`. If you need solution without numpy, using plain Python, and running speed is not an issue, tell me and I'll rewrite, but in plain Python code will work much slower on big data.

You can also [run this code online here](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow63975384#main.py).

```
# Needs: python -m pip install numpy
import numpy as np

word = 'Duck'
key = 1

a = np.frombuffer(word.encode('utf-32-le'), dtype = np.int32)
a = a - key
a[a < 97] += 26

text = a.tobytes().decode('utf-32-le')

print(text)
```

And similar slower next solution but without `numpy`, using just standard Python's built-in module `struct`. You can also [run next code online](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow63975384var2#main.py).

```
import struct

word = 'Duck'
key = 1

text = ''

for i in word:
    c = struct.unpack('<I', i.encode('utf-32-le'))[0] - int(key)
    if c < 97:
        c = c + 26
    b = struct.pack('<I', c).decode('utf-32-le')
    text += b
    
print(text)
```

Another solution below without using any module. [Run next code online](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow63975384var3#main.py).

```
word = 'Duck'
key = 1

text = ''

for i in word:
    c = int(i.encode('utf-32-be').hex(), 16) - int(key)
    if c < 97:
        c = c + 26
    b = bytes.fromhex(hex(c)[2:].zfill(8)).decode('utf-32-be')
    text += b
    
print(text)
```

If text symbols are only from [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) set then code can be simplified even further ([run this code online](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow63975656var4#main.py)):

```
word = 'Duck'
key = 1

text = ''

for i in word:
    c = i.encode('ascii')[0] - int(key)
    if c < 97:
        c = c + 26
    b = bytes((c,)).decode('ascii')
    text += b
    
print(text)
```

One more solution for the case of ASCII chars, using two tables ([run this code online](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow63975656var5#main.py))

```
word = 'Duck'
key = 1

tmp = [(c, i) for i, c in enumerate(bytes(range(128)).decode('ascii'))]
c2i = dict(tmp)
i2c = [e[0] for e in tmp]

text = ''

for i in word:
    c = c2i[i] - int(key)
    if c < 97:
        c = c + 26
    b = i2c[c]
    text += b
    
print(text)
```

Previous code can be extended from ASCII to wider char set (e.g. 16-bit) by replacing next line ([run this code online](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow63975656var6#main.py)):

```
tmp = [(bytes.fromhex(hex(i)[2:].zfill(8)).decode('utf-32-be', 'replace'), i) for i in range(1 << 16)]
```

Comment: Please expound. What is the reason for using `struct`?

Comment: @Pynchia Reason for using struct is due to questioner's request not to use ord/chr, hence `encode/decode + struct unpack/pack` is replacement for ord/chr.

Comment: Maybe there is an easier way to convert 4 bytes to int and back, rather than `struct`.

Comment: I may also use `int(bytes_.hex(), 16)`.

Comment: Added solution without any modules.

Comment: Anyway `numpy` solution is the fastest to run and may process large texts without any loops. Also shortest in length code.

Comment: Also code can be simplified if text contains only ascii chars. I expected any symbols in text, hence used UTF-32 encoding.